# why is using .index() faster than using a for loop?

Tags: python-2.7

I want to find a match in a huge list and return the value. I was using the following:

```
def func(x)
    for i in list:
        if i == x:
        return i
    return False
```

Surprisingly, after replacing this method with .index:

```
def func(x):
    try:
        return i.index(x)
    except Valueerror:
        return False
```

The testing time was reduced 10 times. Why is that? Or what is the different between index and for loop?

Comment: `index` is convenient (also implemented in C probably).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply because python built-ins are implemented in C and python code runs in a C code loop.

So when you use a python function that's implemented in C, it will be much faster than creating your own version of it in python

Comment: I realize that my for loop is forcing it to go through the csv file line by line. -Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the `Array` class is implemented directly in C for efficiency reasons (at least in the MRI version of Ruby) and so, it is much faster.

here's [the source](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-index):

```
               static VALUE
rb_str_index_m(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE str)
{
    VALUE sub;
    VALUE initpos;
    long pos;

    if (rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "11", &sub, &initpos) == 2) {
        pos = NUM2LONG(initpos);
    }
    else {
        pos = 0;
    }
    if (pos < 0) {
        pos += str_strlen(str, NULL);
        if (pos < 0) {
            if (RB_TYPE_P(sub, T_REGEXP)) {
                rb_backref_set(Qnil);
            }
            return Qnil;
        }
    }

    if (SPECIAL_CONST_P(sub)) goto generic;
    switch (BUILTIN_TYPE(sub)) {
      case T_REGEXP:
        if (pos > str_strlen(str, NULL))
            return Qnil;
        pos = str_offset(RSTRING_PTR(str), RSTRING_END(str), pos,
                         rb_enc_check(str, sub), single_byte_optimizable(str));

        pos = rb_reg_search(sub, str, pos, 0);
        pos = rb_str_sublen(str, pos);
        break;

      generic:
      default: {
        VALUE tmp;

        tmp = rb_check_string_type(sub);
        if (NIL_P(tmp)) {
            rb_raise(rb_eTypeError, "type mismatch: %s given",
                     rb_obj_classname(sub));
        }
        sub = tmp;
      }
        /* fall through */
      case T_STRING:
        pos = rb_str_index(str, sub, pos);
        pos = rb_str_sublen(str, pos);
        break;
    }

    if (pos == -1) return Qnil;
    return LONG2NUM(pos);
}
```